# SQL*Loader : data loading with treatments

Tags: sql-loader

i want to load some data with SQL*Loader by the following steps:
-load some columns of data in the text file.
-make transformations into some data during loading.
my file lines format is a sequence of   like this:

```
123 G 100 data 122 EGG ....
123 G 100 date2 122 EGG ....
```

firstly : just the value columns must be loaded, i mean : "G", "data" and "EGG" for the first line and "G", "data2" & "EGG" for the second line etc. the s corresponf to the field ids.

secondly : i need in some case, to split some columns to 3 parts and that will correspond to 3 records in table.

Global issue : I need just to know how to couple date loading and date treatment at same time.

also, in need in some case, to split some columns to 3 parts and that will correspond to 3 records in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly:
Every column in the data file needs to be accounted for.  If you don't want to load it to a table, just specify it as FILLER:

```
...
( NBR1  FILLER   -- '123'
 ,data1 char     -- 'G'
 ,NBR2  FILLER   -- '100'
 ,data2 char     -- 'data'
 ,NBR3  FILLER   -- '122'
...
```

The rest of your questions need some before/after examples of what you are working with and what you expect in order to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the secend issue was as following :

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the secend issue was as following : I have a value into my file as "ABC". during my upload i want split "ABC" string and upload each latter on a row. row for A, row for B and row for C. is it possible in sql loader?